# skincaption issue while building project in Delphi

Tags: delphi-7, pascal, delphi

I am a beginner in Delphi.
I tried importing an existing .dpr project into delphi 7.
When I try to build it, I got these errors

```
"Field MainForm.SkinCaption does not have corresponding component"
"Field MainForm.SkinCaption does not have corresponding component"

File not found SkinCaption.dcu.
```

Please suggest.

Below is the content of .cfg file if required.
-$M16384,1048576
-K$00400000
-LE"c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Projects\Bpl"
-LN"c:\program files\borland\delphi7\Projects\Bpl"
-U"D:\App\Delphi7\Components\VCLSkin\D7"
-O"D:\App\Delphi7\Components\VCLSkin\D7"
-I"D:\App\Delphi7\Components\VCLSkin\D7"
-R"D:\App\Delphi7\Components\VCLSkin\D7"
-w-UNSAFE_TYPE
-w-UNSAFE_CODE
-w-UNSAFE_CAST

P.S. I am using Windows 7 32 bit machine

Comment: The error reports are informative. Do you have the `SkinCaption` component installed?

Comment: Please talk to the person who provided you with the code and get them to help you install the designtime package for the necessary components

Comment: I don't think so as I have installed Delphi 7 from source and using standard component. Can you please guide how to do that. Itried googling the same but dint find any related components to install

Comment: If you are a beginner, then you are doing it wrong. You should start small and work up. Taking an existing program, that is skinned, will be way beyond your competence level.

Comment: You need to purchase (if you do not already have a license), download and install the [VCLSkin](http://www.link-rank.com/feature.htm) component into your IDE.  Your project has a dependency on it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's part of the VCLSkin package - see this [link](http://www.link-rank.com/feature.htm). Unfortunately it's not free. According to the website, you just drop the component on a form and don't need to change any source code. So hopefully you can remove it fairly easy by just ignoring the errors when opening the project. That should remove the VCLSkin components from the forms. If it still complains about the SkinCaption unit, just remove it from the uses clause in the form units. Just make backups of your source code before doing anything! Alternatively you can try to install the demo version on their site. However, being a beginner in Delphi, you might wait before you start bother with adding skins to your projects!